# Sorting a list in C# with special characters

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting

I have a `List<string>` with the following values:

`1 / 324324
10 / 324234
61 / 917752
62 / 917762
7 / 917718
8 / 917719
9 / 917720`

I want them to be sorted as following based on the numbers before the forward slash:

`1 / 324324
7 / 917718
8 / 917719
9 / 917720
10 / 324234
61 / 917752
62 / 917762`

Since they are string values, the list.sort() method does't work.

Any ideaS?

Comment: And what have you tried so far? You want to sort numerically by the number before the `/`. So you'll need to `Split` each string and then `Parse` the first part and sort on that.

Comment: @MattBurland thanks for the comment. !Giorgi answer my query. I was trying to get a substring of the characters before / which didnt work either. But the split works. Thanks again

Comment: Be sure to accept Giorgi's answer then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can split the items by slash and sort by the number:

```
var sorted  = input.OrderBy(a=>int.Parse(a.Split('/')[0]));
```

Comment: Actually, You don't need to trim. Those extra leading or trailing spaces will be ignored by [int.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx). It only needs to be in the form of `[ws][sign]digits[ws]`

Answer (score 0):

To do it using `List<T>.Sort()` method

```
// init list
var list = new List<String>();

// add items
// some code here

// sort items
list.Sort((s1, s2) => 
{
    var n1 = Int32.Parse(s1.Split('/')[0]);
    var n2 = Int32.Parse(s2.Split('/')[0]);

    return n1 - n2;
});
```

using linq you can do it like

```
var sortedList = list.OrderBy(item=> Int32.Parse(item.Split('/')[0])).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values on the left of the slash are unique, you could split the string on the slash, trim the values and add them to a [sorted list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx).  Then you could let the framework do the work for you.